# The date/time format used in HTTP headers

Tags: php, http, date, rfc

Which RFC describes the format used for date/time in the modern time HTTP headers, like "Last-Modified" and "If-Modified-Since", and how to generate a date/time string in PHP according to such format?

Some sources point to RFC 2822, which, as indicated by [DateTime](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) class, is using `D, d M Y H:i:s O` format, but from my tests, this format produces `+0000` instead of `GMT` at the end. I tried other timezone specifiers but none of them seems to put `GMT` at the end, the closest result I got was with `UTC`. However, as was shown by Firebug, all sites are using `GMT` in HTTP headers and not `+0000` or `UTC`.

So what format is really used and how do I format date/time in the same way as other sites do?

Comment: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1

Answer (score 82, accepted):

As you can see [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields), **`Last-Modified` header has datetimes in [RFC2616](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616) format**.

In section [`14.29 Last-Modified`](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-14.29) you can see that date format should be:

```
"Last-Modified" ":" HTTP-date
```

An example of its use is

```
Last-Modified: Tue, 15 Nov 1994 12:45:26 GMT
```

Another quote from RFC2616 <sup>[read more](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.3)</sup> :

> All HTTP date/time stamps MUST be represented in Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), without exception.

In PHP you can use format `D, d M Y H:i:s T` if you use function `gmdate()` which always returns datetime in GMT offset/timeszone:

```php
echo gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T');
```

If you wish to use `DateTime` extension:

```
$dt = new DateTime('UTC');
#$dt = new DateTime('2013-01-01 12:00:00', new DateTimezone('UTC'));
echo $dt->format('D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T');
```

Comment: But the prevalent number of other date string on that page you are referencing to are using the GMT format (7 examples use GMT and just 1 example +0000). And, for example, the USA Today site is responding with the following headers: Last-Modified: Tue, 14 Jan 2014 18:48:38 GMT; Expires: Tue, 14 Jan 2014 18:50:58 GMT; Date: Tue, 14 Jan 2014 18:50:38 GMT, so all are using GMT.

Comment: GMT is _Greenwich Mean Time_ it's absolute.

Comment: Ok, apparently `gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s T", 123456)` is producing strings with GMT, so thanks anyways.

Comment: You are citing the wrong spec. What's relevant is http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/rfc2616.html#rfc.section.3.3.1 (or the spec that's going to replace it: http://greenbytes.de/tech/webdav/draft-ietf-httpbis-p2-semantics-25.html#rfc.section.7.1.1.1)

Comment: `DATE_RFC7231` constant added in PHP 7.0.19, [in this commit](http://git.php.net/?p=php-src.git;a=commit;h=618d97962a8ac59d981c8307cc704790f46090c8)

Answer (score 21):

Well, let's have a look at RFC 2616 which defines HTTP 1.1:
https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616#section-3.3

> HTTP applications have historically allowed three different formats for the representation of date/time stamps:
>
> ```
>  Sun, 06 Nov 1994 08:49:37 GMT  ; RFC 822, updated by RFC 1123
>  Sunday, 06-Nov-94 08:49:37 GMT ; RFC 850, obsoleted by RFC 1036
>  Sun Nov  6 08:49:37 1994       ; ANSI C's asctime() format
> ```
>
> The first format is preferred as an Internet standard and represents a fixed-length subset of that defined by RFC 1123 [8] (an update to RFC 822 [9]).
>
> (...)
>
> All HTTP date/time stamps MUST be represented in Greenwich Mean Time (GMT), without exception.

So `DateTime::COOKIE` or `Datetime::RFC850` use a valid format. The preferred one according to the RFC would be `D, d M Y H:i:s T` which is not defined by any constant in the `DateTime` class.

To make sure that GMT is used, the following code should suffice:

```
gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s T');
```

Comment: There is a constant for the preferred format `DateTime::RFC1123`/`DATE_RFC1123`.

Comment: That’s close but not the same. It uses `O` in the end instead of `T`, which will return `+0000` instead of `GMT` (as required by the standard).

Answer (score 4):

I'm pretty sure the (now) correct answer here is [rfc7231 - section 7.1.1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1) It specifies Date/Time Formats and is where the `HTTP-date` semantics are defined.

```
HTTP-date    = IMF-fixdate / obs-date
```

Also we can see that

> When a sender generates a header field that contains one or more
> timestamps defined as **HTTP-date**, the sender **MUST** generate those
> timestamps in the **IMF-fixdate** format.

So for a server sending a "modern time HTTP header"- where the value is a `HTTP-date` the format is equivalent to the `IMF-fixdate` format.

So to answer the actual question.

> Which RFC describes the format used for date/time in the modern time
> HTTP headers

You need to know the definition of  `IMF-fixdate` - which is in rfc7231.
It also give the definition of `obs-date` too i.e `rfc850-date` / `asctime-date`

```
     IMF-fixdate  = day-name "," SP date1 SP time-of-day SP GMT
     ; fixed length/zone/capitalization subset of the format
     ; see Section 3.3 of [RFC5322]

     day-name     = %x4D.6F.6E ; "Mon", case-sensitive
                  / %x54.75.65 ; "Tue", case-sensitive
                  / %x57.65.64 ; "Wed", case-sensitive
                  / %x54.68.75 ; "Thu", case-sensitive
                  / %x46.72.69 ; "Fri", case-sensitive
                  / %x53.61.74 ; "Sat", case-sensitive
                  / %x53.75.6E ; "Sun", case-sensitive


     date1        = day SP month SP year
                  ; e.g., 02 Jun 1982

     day          = 2DIGIT
     month        = %x4A.61.6E ; "Jan", case-sensitive
                  / %x46.65.62 ; "Feb", case-sensitive
                  / %x4D.61.72 ; "Mar", case-sensitive
                  / %x41.70.72 ; "Apr", case-sensitive
                  / %x4D.61.79 ; "May", case-sensitive
                  / %x4A.75.6E ; "Jun", case-sensitive
                  / %x4A.75.6C ; "Jul", case-sensitive
                  / %x41.75.67 ; "Aug", case-sensitive
                  / %x53.65.70 ; "Sep", case-sensitive
                  / %x4F.63.74 ; "Oct", case-sensitive
                  / %x4E.6F.76 ; "Nov", case-sensitive
                  / %x44.65.63 ; "Dec", case-sensitive
     year         = 4DIGIT

     GMT          = %x47.4D.54 ; "GMT", case-sensitive

     time-of-day  = hour ":" minute ":" second
                  ; 00:00:00 - 23:59:60 (leap second)

     hour         = 2DIGIT
     minute       = 2DIGIT
     second       = 2DIGIT

   Obsolete formats:

     obs-date     = rfc850-date / asctime-date

     rfc850-date  = day-name-l "," SP date2 SP time-of-day SP GMT
     date2        = day "-" month "-" 2DIGIT
                  ; e.g., 02-Jun-82

     day-name-l   = %x4D.6F.6E.64.61.79    ; "Monday", case-sensitive
            / %x54.75.65.73.64.61.79       ; "Tuesday", case-sensitive
            / %x57.65.64.6E.65.73.64.61.79 ; "Wednesday", case-sensitive
            / %x54.68.75.72.73.64.61.79    ; "Thursday", case-sensitive
            / %x46.72.69.64.61.79          ; "Friday", case-sensitive
            / %x53.61.74.75.72.64.61.79    ; "Saturday", case-sensitive
            / %x53.75.6E.64.61.79          ; "Sunday", case-sensitive


     asctime-date = day-name SP date3 SP time-of-day SP year
     date3        = month SP ( 2DIGIT / ( SP 1DIGIT ))
                  ; e.g., Jun  2
```

Answer (score 4):

With DateTime extension, you can use the the RFC7231 constant which refer to the RFC7231 Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP/1.1): Semantics and Content, [chapter 7.1.1.1 Date/Time Formats](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7231#section-7.1.1.1)

```php
$httpDate = $dateTime->format(DateTimeInterface::RFC7231);
```

The constant value is actually the same string as proposed in other answers here `D, d M Y H:i:s \G\M\T`

Answer (score -4):

Via Carbon:

```
Carbon::now()->setTimezone('GMT')->format("D, d M Y H:i:s T")
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. The question is "Which format is used", not how to generate it