# Datetime format change the number of returned rows in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, date-format

I really dont get this...

This first statement below returns the expected rows - ONLY rows which have a date which are BEFORE/SMALLER than...

```
select matchdate, price, size, issell from matchmsg 
where matchdate <= '2015-01-17 00:00:00.000000+01' order by matchdate asc
```

The code below return rows with dates up to the 2015-01-21...!?

```
select matchdate, price, size, issell from matchmsg 
where matchdate <= 'Sat Jan 17 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100' order by matchdate asc
```

PS: I use PostgresSQL, NodeJS and NPM Moment...BUT the result is from the PostgreSQL tool pgAminIII...so - it has nothing to do with my own code...!

matchdate in the DB is a "datetime with time zone" like:

> "2015-01-16 00:00:22.491956+01"

Comment: What is the type of `matchdate`?

Comment: From table def: matchdate timestamp with time zone

If i remove "GTM+0100"

The statement return the same number of rows!?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PostgreSQL does not understand dates of the format `Sat Jan 17 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100` but it's probably trying its best.  Here are tables of the [dates](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-DATE-TABLE) and [time](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TIME-TABLE) formats it does understand.  [A complete explanation can be found here](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/datetime-input-rules.html).

You'll have to convert `Sat Jan 17 2015 00:00:00 GMT+0100` to a format Postgres understands.  It is very close to [the HTTP date format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21120882/the-date-time-format-used-in-http-headers).